# d3 text directly on mouse pointer

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to display some text on mouse pointer on d3 barchart.

I used mousemove event, but there are some unexpected independents. (text displayed top-left from mouse pointer, not direct on it)

[js fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/2Ldoce6n/)

```
    .on("mousemove", function (actual, i) {
          focusText
      .html(actual.value )
      .attr("x", d3.mouse(this)[0])
      .attr("y", d3.mouse(this)[1])
      //alert(d3.mouse(this)[0])
      ;
    }
    )

 var focusText = svg
    .append('g')
    .append('text')
      .style("opacity", 0)
      //.attr("text-anchor", "left")
      //.attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
      //.attr("background", "#ddd")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the margins to the new cursor position:

```
.attr("x", d3.mouse(this)[0] + margin.width)
.attr("y", d3.mouse(this)[1] + margin.height)
```

then probably add some css class with [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to  prevent cursor style change when you hover the text itself.

hope it helps ;)